# should I call the [super superMethod] after my own code or before it?

Tags: objective-c, ios, oop

[sorry for my weak english]

The question is simple (but I have troubles in expressing it and finding it in google)...

Should I (in all similar cases, when I override the super method, not only this one) use:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    /*
       my code
     */

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

or

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    /*
       my code
     */
}
```

or does it depend?

Comment: Generally speaking, the `super` call should be at the start of the routine when "building up", and at the end when "tearing down".

Answer (score 6):

in some cases the order will not matter. in others, order is critical.

some generalizations which will help:

- when you are constructing a portion of the object's state (`viewDidLoad` and `init...`),   call through `super` first.
- when you are destructing a portion of the object's state (`viewDidUnload` or `dealloc`), call through `super` last.
- if i am certain that the order does not matter, then i just call through `super` first for easier organization.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the method; e.g. `-[super init]` (before) vs `-[super dealloc]` (after).

Comment: all right TNX, but somebody should maybe say more about this topic here :)