# Super class method placement in child class

Tags: objective-c, ios, inheritance, initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I call super?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906704/when-should-i-call-super)

Is there is difference/preferred way when placing calls to the super class methods like `[super viewDidLoad]` or `[super init]` or `[super viewDidUnload]`? I have seen tutorials putting them either in the first line or as the last line in a child class method. I am just wondering if there would be any dependency like if the super class method would do some setup the child could use **when called upfront** or if the super could do some optimizations to something the child has done **when called at the end**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I call super?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906704/), [Should I call the \[super superMethod\] after my own code or before it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441519/), [Top or bottom super call in overridden method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019031/), [Placing calls to super](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466889/), [Does the timing of calling the method of the super class matter in ObjectiveC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005196/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My general rule of thumb is that acts of construction/creation call through `super` first, while acts of destruction or tearing down state happen in reverse order -- `super` is called last. There's rarely a need to deviate from that.

The reason is not typically for optimization (as asked in your post), but for predictable *semantics*.

**Example A:**

construction:

```
- (id)init
{
  self = [super init]; // << set up super
  if (0 != self) {
    // set up self
  ...
```

destruction:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
  [ivar release], ivar = 0; // << tear down self
  [super dealloc]; // << tear down super
```

**Example B:**

construction:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)pAnimated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:pAnimated]; // << call through super first
  // now set up self
  ...
```

destruction:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)pAnimated
{
  // tear down self
  [super viewDidDisappear:pAnimated]; // << now tear down super
```

Comment: I just covered `init` but you are perfectly right.

Answer (score 0):

You must initialise the super *first*, because the super constructor has the option to return a value other than the original value of `self`.

```
self = [super init];
```

If you initialise other properties of `self` before calling `[super init]`, these changes may be erased.

*What on earth is that for?*

@Justin notes that Class Clusters (used when returning instances of NSDictionary or NSString) uses this mechanism to provide a slightly different subclass depending upon the task.  Singletons can also use this, and the (now deprecated) `Pose` function of Objective-C could as well.

Comment: I don't know whether this ever actually happens in practice, but you have to abide by the rules.

Comment: it does happen. class clusters and singletons are the notable examples.

Comment: I thought about singletons, and then a cold chill ran through me.  It doesn't seem like a good idea to initialise subclasses after receiving a singleton - the original might have been of a different subclass, or have running data.

Comment: Class clusters - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.htmlOh, that seems reasonable.

Comment: i don't like singletons, but that doesn't stop people from writing them :) one initialization pattern of an objc singleton implementation will just stash the first instance created -- if a new instance is requested, the first instance is returned. however, that design is practically sealed to subclassing.

Comment: yes, class clusters are reasonable. however, it's not normal for many people to create and derive from leaves of class clusters -- so it's unusual to actually be returned another instance from the superclass' initializer at the abstraction level most of us work at (unless you happen to be developing class clusters).

Comment: Some of this flew over my head, but thank you @justin and Alex-Brown for helping me out. I have a better understanding on how this should be implemented now, as justin mentioned in the first answer.